# how to run php code on submit button without refreshing/ reloading the page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, submit, page-refresh

I want to execute some php code on submit button click without refreshing/reloading my page. Is it possible? also i have javascript function on page load that's why i don't want to refresh my page. 
thanks in advance.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["search"]))
{
$show = "SELECT * FROM data";
$rs = mysql_query($show) or die(mysql_error());
 $add_to_textbox = "<input type='button' name='btn' value='add' />";
#****results in Grid****
    echo "<table width='360px' border='1' cellpadding='2'>";
    $rowID=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='130px' id='name.$rowID.'>$row[Name]</td>";
    echo "<td width='230px' id='link.$rowID.'><a href = '$row[Link]'>$row[Link]</a></td>";
    echo "<td width='130px' onclick='Display($rowID);'>$add_to_textbox</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $rowID++;
}
    echo "</table>";
#**********************
mysql_free_result($rs);
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Display(rowID){
    var linkVal = document.getElementById('link'+rowID+'').innerHTML.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "\n");
    document.getElementById("name").value = document.getElementById('name'+rowID+'').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("link").value = linkVal; 
    }
</script>
```

here is my code

Comment: Use `ajax`, you can google it.

Comment: can you show me how? @polin

Comment: @Bkay well it is really important 4 you to know exactly what ajax does. It can be done on server and client side, hit database or not. So for initial knowledge plz go to w3schools.com for initial konwledge

Comment: @polin i have searched it a lot but still didn't find the appropriate answer. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you need to use the javascript / ajax.

Example: on your submit link (a href for exaple), add call-in-to js function `submitMe` and pass on whatever variables you need

```
function submitMe() {
    jQuery(function($) {    
        $.ajax( {           
            url : "some_php_page.php?action=getsession",
            type : "GET",
            success : function(data) {
                alert ("works!"); //or use data string to show something else
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

IF you want to change some content dynamically, it is easy- you just need to create  tags, and assign ID to them : `<div id="Dynamic"> </div>`

Then you load ANYTHING between those two tags using

```
document.getElementById("Dynamic").innerHTML = "<b>BOOM!</b>";
```

Meaning that you calling area between two tags and loading something into them. The same way you GET data from that place:

```
alert(document.getElementById("Dynamic").innerHTML);
```

Please read this: 
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-getelementbyid.php

In addition, play and experiment with DOM elements and learn how they interact. It is not hard, just takes some time to grasp all concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you send request ajax (with plain js anyway) from a html form, make sure you add the return false statement to prevent redirection:
something like:

```
<form method="post" ... onsubmit="ajax_post(); return false;">
```

You have to use ajax, but you can do it in plain javascript (without jquery). Jquery makes it easier.

plain javascript example: This function will trigger an ajax, via get, without parameter: you can tweak it so it run in POST and be able to send some parameter: *file* represent the php file to request and *html* represent the container whre the data will be displayed:

```
function plain_ajax(file,html){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
          r=new XMLHttpRequest();   //For Most BRowser
    } else{ 
          r=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  //for Explorer
    }

    //When the state change
    r.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
       //ReadyState 4 = Loaded     see: http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20060405/
       //status 200 = ok           see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
       if(r.readyState==4 && r.status==200){
           //Replace the content with the response, Using creatDocumentFragment is more efficient 
           //at the cost of a few more lines But it  would alos allow you to append the data
           //instead of replacing it using innerHTML;
           document.getElementById(html).innerHTML = r.responseText;
        }
    }

    //Opening the connection and sending the request.
    r.open("GET",file,true); 
    r.send();
}
```

Comment: if(r.readyState==4 && r.status==200)
can u please explain this line of code?

Comment: When the 'state 'change' it check if the request was completed successfully (200). If so it will replace the content of (html) by the response

Comment: I've commented the script and added few documentation. In reality it's prety simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML or PHP form

```
<form action="submit.php"  method="post">
Name: <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /><br />
Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
Phone Number: <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" /><br />
<input type="button" id="searchForm" onclick="SubmitForm();" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Your JavaScript

```
 <script>
 function SubmitForm() {
 var name = $("#name").val();
 var email = $("#email").val();
 var phone = $("#phone").val();
 $.post("submit.php", { name: name, email: email, phone: phone },
 function(data) {
 alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
 });
 }
 </script>
```

Your PHP page to do some activity

```
 <?php
 echo $_POST['name']."<br />";
 echo $_POST['email']."<br />";
 echo $_POST['phone']."<br />";
 echo "All Data Submitted Sucessfully!"
 ?>
```